# Events in Backbone views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

My backbone.js app has a collection of items. The views for collection and each item render as expected.

Each item has a two actions on it,  lets say A and B. How do I hook up event listeners in my ItemView class such that I can handle actions A and B?

> ```
> window.SourceListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
> tagName: "li",
>
> initialize: function () {
>     this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
>     this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
> },
>
> render: function () {
>     $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
>     return this;
> },
>
> events: {
>    "click .action_a": "doA",
>   "click .action_b": "doB"
>  },
>
> doA: function(event) {
>     alert("A clicked for " + JSON.stringify(event));
> },
>
>
> doB: function(event) {
>     alert("B clicked for " + JSON.stringify(event));
> }
> ```
>
> });

ItemView's template

```
 <a href="#sources/<%=id %>" class="source thumbnail plain" style="text-align: center;">
     <h4><%= name %></h4>
     <button class="btn btn-primary action_a"> A</button>
     <button class="btn btn-info action_b"> B</button> 
 </a>
```

Comment: Trying to understand your problem. doA , doB aren't fired? is that your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems to be the problem:

```
$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

I got it work using this:

```
this.$el.html(test(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Note I changed a number of other things to get it working locally which may or may not be further problems.

- **The view needs to specify a template.**
- **The `<a>` tag contains the buttons.**
- **Had to change JSON.Stringify(event) do functions.**

Working code:

```
    <html>

      <script src="./jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="./underscore.js"></script>
      <script src="./backbone.js"></script>

      <body>
      </body>

      <script>
        window.SourceListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
          tagName: "li",

          initialize: function () {
              this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
              this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
          },

          template: function(data) {
            var compiled = _.template('<a href="#sources/<%=id %>" class="source thumbnail plain" style="text-align: center;"> <h4><%= name %></h4> </a> <button class="btn btn-primary action_a"> A</button> <button class="btn btn-info action_b"> B</button>');
            return compiled;
          },

          render: function () {
              var test = this.template();
              this.$el.html(test(this.model.toJSON()));
              return this;
          },

          events: {
            "click .action_a": "doA",
            "click .action_b": "doB"
          },

          doA: function(event) {
              alert("A clicked for " + JSON.stringify(event));
          },


          doB: function(event) {
              alert("B clicked for " + $(event.srcElement).html());
          }
        });

        testModel = new Backbone.Model({id: 1, name: 'Elias'});
        testRow = new SourceListItemView({model: testModel});
        $('body').append(testRow.render().$el);
      </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think the trick was the <a> tag containing buttons. I removed that and it all worked. Thanks for hinting at that